# Trouble Retrieving Metadata Information from OpenStack Swift Object using REST APIs: Need Help Adding Metadata from Horizon UI or REST API properly

Tags: storage, openstack, object-storage, openstack-swift

I am new to OpenStack Swift and I am trying to add single/multiple metadata to an object using REST APIs. However, although I receive a 202 success response for the request, when I try to retrieve the metadata information using a HEAD request, it returns a 200 success but without the metadata information.

My questions are:

Can metadata be added from the Horizon web UI dashboard? If yes, what are the steps to do that?

Are there any configuration changes required to work with metadata?

[Adding metadata to an object using REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZyMl.png)

[Trying to retrieve metadata using REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMyHP.png)

Just to add some more information I attached swift capabilities command output

```
[root@controller ~]# swift -V 3 capabilities                                                                                                                                                                       Core: swift                                                                                                                                                                                                         Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            account_autocreate: True                                                                                                                                                                                           account_listing_limit: 10000                                                                                                                                                                                       allow_account_management: True                                                                                                                                                                                     container_listing_limit: 10000                                                                                                                                                                                     extra_header_count: 0                                                                                                                                                                                              max_account_name_length: 256                                                                                                                                                                                       max_container_name_length: 256                                                                                                                                                                                     max_file_size: 5368709122                                                                                                                                                                                          max_header_size: 8192                                                                                                                                                                                              max_meta_count: 90                                                                                                                                                                                                 max_meta_name_length: 128                                                                                                                                                                                          max_meta_overall_size: 4096                                                                                                                                                                                        max_meta_value_length: 256                                                                                                                                                                                         max_object_name_length: 1024                                                                                                                                                                                       policies: [{u'default': True, u'name': u'Policy-0', u'aliases': u'Policy-0'}]                                                                                                                                      strict_cors_mode: True                                                                                                                                                                                             version: 2.17.1                                                                                                                                                                                                  Additional middleware: account_quotas                                                                                                                                                                              Additional middleware: bulk_delete                                                                                                                                                                                  Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            max_deletes_per_request: 10000                                                                                                                                                                                     max_failed_deletes: 1000                                                                                                                                                                                         Additional middleware: bulk_upload                                                                                                                                                                                  Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            max_containers_per_extraction: 10000                                                                                                                                                                               max_failed_extractions: 1000                                                                                                                                                                                     Additional middleware: container_quotas                                                                                                                                                                            Additional middleware: crossdomain                                                                                                                                                                                 Additional middleware: formpost                                                                                                                                                                                    Additional middleware: ratelimit                                                                                                                                                                                    Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            account_ratelimit: 0.0                                                                                                                                                                                             container_listing_ratelimits: []                                                                                                                                                                                   container_ratelimits: []                                                                                                                                                                                           max_sleep_time_seconds: 60.0                                                                                                                                                                                     Additional middleware: slo                                                                                                                                                                                          Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            max_manifest_segments: 1000                                                                                                                                                                                        max_manifest_size: 2097152                                                                                                                                                                                         min_segment_size: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                yield_frequency: 10                                                                                                                                                                                              Additional middleware: staticweb                                                                                                                                                                                   Additional middleware: tempurl                                                                                                                                                                                      Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                            allowed_digests: [u'sha1', u'sha256', u'sha512']                                                                                                                                                                   incoming_allow_headers: []                                                                                                                                                                                         incoming_remove_headers: [u'x-timestamp']                                                                                                                                                                          methods: [u'GET', u'HEAD', u'PUT', u'POST', u'DELETE']                                                                                                                                                             outgoing_allow_headers: [u'x-object-meta-public-*']                                                                                                                                                                outgoing_remove_headers: [u'x-object-meta-*']
```

I need a help in adding and retrieving metadata to an object using both horizon UI and REST API way.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake here. If you want to create a metadata for an object then you have to follow the key naming convention below

X-Object-Meta-:

instead in wrongly used X-Container-Meta-: